# How to use UserData Observable Object in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In an Xcode SwiftUI project, I have a `TextField` in which user write the username.

I want that the username will be kept in memory when the user close the app.

So, I created a `UserData.swift` in which there are `utilisateur` and a boolean var :

```
final class UserData: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var utilisateur = ""
    @Published var connected = false
}
```

On my `ContentView`, I wrote this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
```

and in the code, for each case I wrote one of these 3 possibilities.

```
self.userData.utilisateur
userData.utilisateur
userData.$utilisateur
```

Moreover, in `SceneDelegate.swift`, I wrote this :

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(UserData()))
```

The problem is that when I close the app, the `utilisateur` value is deleted and not kept in memory.

Does someone know where is my mistake and what should I do to correct it?

Comment: Store it in UserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserData` is not saved on disk. It remains in the memory but when you close your application it's gone. One way is to persist your data with `UserDefaults`:

```
//save
UserDefaults.standard.set(connected, forKey: "connected")

//read
let connected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "connected")
```

You can find more information here:

- [Storing user settings with UserDefaults](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/storing-user-settings-with-userdefaults)
- [Apple documentation of *UserDefaults*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

To integrate it with your existing code you can use `didSet` on your `@Published` properties:

```
final class UserData: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var connected: Bool {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(connected, forKey: "connected")
        }
    }

    init() {
        _connected = .init(initialValue: UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "connected"))
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, your code says that default value of `connected` is `false`?  Or have I to set it somewhere ?
Also, I do this in my UserData.swift, and in my ContentView it's ok I have nothing to change ?

Comment: At the beginning your `UserDefaults` are empty. So when you search for the `connected` key it returns `false`. And you don't need to change your `ContentView`. The whole idea is to keep your View separated from how your store your model.